# Error launching IDEA intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have got myself a new laptop Asus it runs on Windows 10 x64.

I have downloaded on this laptop java 10.0.2 and the latest version of intellij.

I did open once the intellij yesterday but today I wanted to open it again and im keep getting that error

[image]

I tried to google it out and I entered my variable environment and I did define that `JAVA_HOME` but it did nothing...

[image]

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: _... I did define that `JAVA_HOME`..._ How di you  do it? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52081848/edit) the post and add an image of it?

Comment: i added the post mate you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

there are to chances causing this:

1. Wrong JDK - check whether you have downloaded the JDK for x64, and if not download it and install the correct one. JDK download site [click here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html)
2. Environmental variable is not set properly - Here is the guideline to set Environmental variables [click here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)

Comment: thank you for the help but im sorry i checked 10 times it is the x64 jdk and i did the java home variable right.. but i do have some new info i just tried to right click the intellij app and tried ro "run as administrator" and i actually did it i was available to enter and use the app. but why cant i open it regualry i dont get it??

Comment: Are you using a shortcut when it fails? If so, make sure it's not pointing to an old IntelliJ installation.

Comment: i do using a shortcut, how can i make sure it points the right one?

Comment: Right click in the shortcut > properties (or something like that). There must be a "field" with the location it is pointing to. Make sure that location is the same as where the app you're launching the app as "Administrator" is located.

Comment: yes the shortcut leads to the same point where my app is located.. this is just weird why i can open in as a administrator but not just regualry

Comment: Do you have multiple users in that PC? Did you install it as "Administrator"? Maybe that's the problem. Try using the shortcut, but run it too as "Administrator" if it runs OK, then it is a permissions issue.

Comment: well in my laptop only 1 user but it is the same microsoft user that is located on my regular computer. and im not even sure how to install as a administartor oof :( i guess ill just run it permentally as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

To permanently run as administrator follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the program folder of the program you want to run. For example, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 8.0\Acrobat.
2. Right-click the program icon (the .exe file).
3. Choose Properties.
4. On the Compatibility tab, select the Run This Program As An Administrator option.
   Click OK.

Comment: I followed the steps and now i can run the app kinda regulary wappell i guess its not counting as solving the problem but who cares if it runs. so thank you very much for your time appreciated.